# Getting JSON formatting error for Datatables with executing any JSON code

Tags: jquery, spring, rest, datatables

I'm using JQuery Datatables using ajax calls to get server data. I've successfully done this in the past. The new thing I've tried this time is passing 3 parameters with fnServerParams.

In the jsp I have:

```
<script>
    <%--Initializes the datatable --%>
    var userNameJs = "${userName}";
    var startDateJs = "${startDate}";
    var endDateJs = "${endDate}";

    $(document).ready(function() {

            var oTable = $('#userSearchItems')
                .dataTable(
                    {
                    "bProcessing": true,
                    "iCookieDuration": 3600,
                    "bPaginate" : true,
                    "bServerSide": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                    "aaSorting":[[0,'asc']],
                    "sAjaxSource": '/kb/report/view/searchesByUserOverDatesAjax/{userName}/{startDate}/{endDate}',
                    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                        aoData.push({ "name": "userName", "value": userNameJs});
                        aoData.push({ "name": "startDate", "value": startDateJs});
                        aoData.push({ "name": "endDate", "value": endDateJs});
                    }
                    });
    });
</script>

<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" class="zebra-striped bordered-table" id="userSearchItems">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>When Entered</th>
                <th >Search Term</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td></td>
               <td style="word-wrap: break-word"></td>
          </tr>         
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

In the Spring Controller I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchesByUserOverDatesAjax/{userName}/{startDate}/{endDate}{", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String searchesByUserOverDates(@PathVariable("userName") String userName,
    @PathVariable("startDate") String startDate, @PathVariable("endDate") String endDate) {
System.out.print("HERE IN AJAX");
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
```

I get a popup error :

DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.

But the method searchesByUserOverDates() never executes. In FireBug/Net it show that I received a 200 OK from the HTTP call and parameters were sent ok but my sysout and debug breakpoints never get hit.

It doesn't seem to be dispatching the method. I get no errors in the log or in the js error console.

I see that there were some pre-JQuery issues with this error message pre jQuery 1.4 but we are at 1.8

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Ah something dumb ... extra { at the end of the java method parm.

Now it works. Funny the compiler or Spring mvc never caught that.

Cheers